# Process ID of RDP File

Tags: c#, winforms, process

I am trying to get process ID of the .rdp file that is opened by process and kill it with button1_Click but visual studio throws error that the process id doesn't exit.
I checked the taskbar and the rdp file has different process id , not the one i captured from following code. If I just call mstc.exe, it works fine and i am able to kill the process without any error.
Anyone can help me with this.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pids.Clear();
    Process myprocess = new Process();
    myprocess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\rdp\\RemoteIn.rdp";  
    //notePad.StartInfo.FileName = "mstsc.exe";                
    myprocess.Start();        
    pids.Add(myprocess);          
}

private void terminateAll()
{          
    foreach (var i in pids)
    {
       // Process p = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        i.Kill();
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    terminateAll();
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a solution to this? I'm hitting the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you START a non `exe` file via the `Process` class it will use the `ShellExecute` function to lookup the handler for that file an indireclty launch the process.

Fortunatly `mstsc.exe` will take command line paramters, so you can launch `mstsc.exe` and directly.

```
myprocess.StartInfo.FileName = "mstsc.exe";                
myprocess.StartInfo.Arguments = "C:\\rdp\\RemoteIn.rdp";  
myprocess.Start();
```